# Is a .txt expected to be in UTF-8 encoding these days? Must I end it with .utf8?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, ascii, plaintext

I'm producing plain-text files. I do not use ASCII/ANSI but UTF-8 encoding, since the year is 2020 and not 1995. `Unicode/UTF-8` is very well established now and it would be madness to assume no UTF-8 support these days.

At the same time, I have a feeling that plain-text files `(.txt)` are associated with `ANSI/ASCII` encoding, as in, because it's so primitive-looking it must also be primitive in the encoding it uses.

However, I wish to use all kinds of Unicode characters, and not just be limited to the basic `ANSI/ASCII` ones.

Since plain-text has no metadata like HTML does, there is (beknownst to me) no way to tell the reader that this `.txt` uses `Unicode/UTF-8`, and from what I have learned, you cannot `detect` it reliably but have to make "educated guesses".

I have seen people add `.utf8` to the end of text files before, but this seems kind of ugly and I strongly question how widespread support for this is...

Should I do this?

```
test.txt.utf8
```

Whenever the .txt file is using UTF-8? Or will it just make it even harder for people to open them with no actual benefit in terms of detecting it as UTF-8?

Comment: `These days` actually started in 1995, when Windows NT, Java, Javascript came out with native Unicode support. UTF8 is *indistinguishable* from US-ASCII - that's the point. It uses the exact same bytes and characters for the first 127 characters. UTF16 and other encodings, *do* have metadata - the BOM at the start of the file

Comment: Nobody puts `.utf8` at the end of files to mark them as UTF8 - in fact, that's the first time I've seen anyone mention that. And I live in a non-English country, which means Unicode and codepages were a constant problem before 2000. The `utf8` extension does *nothing* either - no language recognizes this, so all will read it as if it were a text file. Many languages/libraries will detect and use the BOM if it exists. Without that, they'll use the user's preferences - on Linux, they'll use the encoding specified in LC_CTYPE, LANG or LC_ALL. On Windows, it's the user's locale settings.

Comment: Given that US-ASCII and UTF8 are identical, UTF8 is a sensible default for languages and libraries, unless the user specifies a non-Unicode codepage. NET's StreamReader for example [defaults to Encoding.UTF8](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,133). So the question really is - do you need to read non-English, non-Unicode files?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos UTF-8 and US-ASCII are not at all identical. ASCII is undefined above code point 127, UTF-8 uses those bytes to encode characters one way, legacy 8-bit encodings like Latin-1 and Windows code page 1252 use those bytes to encode completely different code points using different logic. But I agree that `.txt` continues to be a good convention, and that the encoding can often be inferred on many platforms, other than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You do not elaborate on the use case of the text files you generate, but actually the "way to tell the reader that this .txt uses Unicode/UTF-8" is the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the text file. By the way it is represented in actual bytes, it tells the reader which Unicode encoding to use to read the file.

From the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html):

```
Bytes           Encoding Form
00 00 FE FF     UTF-32, big-endian
FF FE 00 00     UTF-32, little-endian
FE FF           UTF-16, big-endian
FF FE           UTF-16, little-endian
EF BB BF        UTF-8
```

Comment: A lot of software has no BOM support. So in practice, it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: The usefulness of and tolerance for unnecessary BOMs are platform-dependent. Windows victims tend to need BOMs and find them useful even when they don't, while the opposite tends to hold on other platforms.